# how to find a sequence of digits in base b such that each consecutive block of size k appears exactly once?

Tags: graph-theory, markov-chains, co.combinatorics

My question is most precisely stated in the title. As an example, if we consider base 10, and k=4, then I am asking, is it possible to have a sequence of length 10^4 + 3, such that each 4 digit number appear exactly once in a consecutive block? This is related to finding a Hamiltonian cycle in a b-regular graph. But one would also like to construct the actual cycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google for "generating De Bruijn sequences".

Comment: Would this be the shortest correct answer to a mathoverflow question?

Comment: Sorry Mariano. But I couldn't find an algorithm for generating De Bruijn sequence with base other than 2, and even the one for base 2 seems very complicated. Do you have any quick insight on that?